# ReturnType<T> behaving unexpectedly in a TS utility meant to preserve strong types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a `ifArray` function which takes an input and two callback functions that handle the IF and ELSE cases for whether the value *is an array*. The goal is to preserve as narrow a type as is possible considering the inputs.

Here's the code so far:

```
export type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | object | undefined | void | null | {};
export type IsArray<T> = [T] extends [any[]] ? true : [T] extends [readonly any[]] ? true : false;
export type IfArray<T, IF, ELSE> = IsArray<T> extends true ? IF : ELSE;

export function isArray<T>(i: T) {
  return (Array.isArray(i) === true) as IsArray<T>;
}

export function ifArray<
  T extends Narrowable,
  IF extends <N extends T & readonly any[]>(arr: N) => any,
  ELSE extends <N extends Exclude<T, any[]>>(nonArr: N) => any
>(val: T, isAnArray: IF, isNotAnArray: ELSE) {
  return (
    isArray(val) ? isAnArray(val as any) : isNotAnArray(val as any)
    ) as IfArray<
      T,
      ReturnType<IF>,
      ReturnType<ELSE> // this is where things appear to be failing
    >;
}
```

I've created four distinct tests for what I'd like to see for type outcomes:

```
const whatAmI0 = ifArray(
  "developer" as string,
  i => `You are a problem child with ${i.length} personalities` as const,
  i => `You are a ${i}` as const
);

const whatAmI1 = ifArray(
  "developer",
  i => `You are a problem child with ${i.length} personalities` as const,
  i => `You are a ${i}` as const
);

const whatAmI2 = ifArray(
  ["developer", "person", "husband"],
  i => `You are a problem child with ${i.length} personalities` as const,
  i => `You are a ${i}` as const
);

const whatAmI3 = ifArray(
  ["developer", "person", "husband"] as const,
  i => `You are a problem child with ${i.length} personalities` as const,
  i => `You are a ${i}` as const
);
```

[image: test status]

Of these tests, the second one fails and the rest pass. The most important thing for me is to get this test to pass but I also would like to find ways to not require the `as const` expression where ever possible but preserve the narrow types.

### The Failing Test

Looking at test 1 and 2 (aka, `whatAmI0` and `whatAmI1`) you can see that the only difference is that "developer" is passed as an explicit **string** in the first instance (where it works) and then in the second case the string is passed in without expressing type. Because we've defined the value to extend `Narrowable` its type becomes the string literal `developer`. That part seems to work:

[image: type is narrowed]

and I believe the `IfArray<T,IF,ELSE>` works fine too which means that the problem takes place on the line where we are look to return `ReturnType<ELSE>` where it blows up and just return "any" as the type. To help debug things I temporarily wanted to look at the type of ELSE at this point so replaced the `ReturnType<ELSE>` with just `ELSE`:

[image: this looks ok]

Looking at this type I don't understand why the `ReturnType<T>` would fail and it *should* return the value I'm looking for.

### Playground

All of the code mentioned is available here: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAogD1QYxgBpsBHAVwEMAbOAXzgDMoIQ4AiAASVQFp8AFjWooAdgHMUAZwD05GMGpT2AbgBQalHmjweaAHKUoLAO6UARiLgBeOFJhRgEuAB84o8iHMooruOYgIEUpRPylELyC-CHMAKxRCP3JRABMURicUFL8ANwhgbLcPalo3dDp1LUhYBGQ0AEkpAEFjSkQAHgAVAD4bOABtToBdOC0YMRSpAZDEfqGRgH4EKHI0AC4B4dGccdSp-qgUShSIUWpEOBm5xeXVuA3GGikUSu0avTh6xhaoNq6SeoAMRIWAAMgBlLC9WyNH5-HrbXaTW5oJZA+7YCFYdSaN7wRjJQjAU5wYDNVodHoACmAG06AEoMGo4HBDjByFBQlS4YgAHRknk0xnWEUoxmUKawildbrqOgaKo6JiEhQk4DfaXMuCdRETKaGYwQMyWFBELXosZ6uDtfS6vbauAAMlZRxOZwuVyG3SpRigG30wt6MzNLLBkLtyJtEamuHw1HIaX+l1Esy93tEpx+-sDycQam9ORodJIAtEPI2QJLUn0EBgTTLFI2YawjPQWrZHK5WpZAopVML1EZS1LgoHlymM0ZGzJNbrDd+iH7NHHufp3bg4slGoX7XXLM6IZZR4ASih2ZzOnV2kDuoej3BT+fRJfUO1m70ZDIEAIyaSpiYBB8NAYB-CQJzAVAjAQCB-DQR5FCccR11lNR5TUfBTnsOAAMoOsQHqAAGPp1UFLV2DSHIUGoCBUCgdgV3sRwJEPYAbF6AADABNCByEuQ5LjgMAWBNNhBEUbITGAEC4AAEnQYBeRECQQIYWipFOGgpOAaR2JXDDRHsFi2LgLieL4tBKFk+S6F0iU4H0+w1HpHEHPgHC8PqABGYjtzaKkyIoqiaJ8dgjOsDjuN4owLME4SRFEn9qAkqSBCshSlPEFTBJ8dTRE0hQdL0zDiC1VjwpMyLzIEuTgBsoqDJgJyXOK7ChA8gAmHzSJZfpyJQSjqNo0KODU05hvYARyCkcwQhSdghjCiKzOigShJieL7MS5LpJqxSxEygRVJyjTqC0wq7NcxaKuW-jLJquqLuKpqNFc1rcKafCAGYur7LVesCwaQpIdhRtEcbJum2b5vqwzSuM0yotu2L1pQBLxOwlK0r25TDuyqBcvy7SpFsqZLrh8qEaqu7rJJ+ynucjQPnwCVpD6fotVwAgYDfCgaHaPQIEYN6PIIkhKZW6nGMQmzulvDm8ASbmsF56h+bqQXhY+ryxcqiW4AB4KoHY2XD05xWeaoVWBaF9ytfanWbpitaRM29HJJ29APC8Hwjvxk6zuJk35a5i2+etzWvodxGnbi1HXaSjHpO+0HCZ0oOhhUIA).

### Partially Fixed

As so often happens, the energy required to describe your problem activates parts of your brain that hadn't been prior and you solve your problem. I haven't *fully* solved this but I have made that failing test pass by changing the code to:

```
export function ifArray<
  T extends Narrowable,
  IF extends <N extends T & readonly any[]>(arr: N) => any,
  // CHANGED: instead of extending the type with a generic I just
  // just gave it the type as T being narrowable is all that's
  // needed to preserve the narrowness
  ELSE extends (nonArr: Exclude<T, any[]>) => any
>(val: T, isAnArray: IF, isNotAnArray: ELSE) {
  return (
    isArray(val) ? isAnArray(val as any) : isNotAnArray(val as any)
    ) as IfArray<
      T,
      ReturnType<IF>,
      ReturnType<ELSE>
    >;
}
```

Now what remains as a problem is forcing the two functions which are passed in to preserve their narrow typing. I can achieve this by explicitly stating that this parameter is `as const` but that means the user has to remember to do this and I'd prefer -- just like I have with the value `T` -- to make these functions automagically preserve their narrow type props.

So what I'm hoping I can do is have a caller do this:

```
const whatAmI1 = ifArray(
  "developer",
  i => `You are a problem child with ${i.length} personalities` ,
  i => `You are a ${i}`
);
```

instead of this:

```
const whatAmI1 = ifArray(
  "developer",
  i => `You are a problem child with ${i.length} personalities` as const,
  i => `You are a ${i}` as const
);
```

but get the same results.

- [Fixed Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAogD1QYxgBpsBHAVwEMAbOAXzgDMoIQ4AiAASVQFp8AFjWooAdgHMUAZwD05GMGpT2AbgBQalHmjweaAHKUoLAO6UARiLgBeOFJhRgEuAB84o8iHMooruOYgIEUpRPylELyC-CHMAKxRCP3JRABMURicUFL8ANwhgbLcPalo3dDp1LUhYBGQ0AEkpAEFjSkQAHgAVAD4bOABtToBdOC0YMRSpAZDEfqGRgH4EKHI0AC4B4dGccdSp-qgUShSIUWpEOBm5xeXVuA3GGikUSu0avTh6xhaoNq6SeoAMRIWAAMgBlLC9WyNH5-HrbXaTW5oJZA+7YCFYdSaN7wRjJQjAU5wYDNVodHoACmAG06AEoMGo4HBDjByFBQlS4YgAHRknk0xnWEUoxmUKawildbrqOgaKo6JiEhQk4DfaXMuCdRETKaGYwQMyWFBELXosZ6uDtfS6vbauAAMlZRxOZwuVyG3SpRigG30wt6MzNLLBkLtyKpolOPw2uHw1HIaX+l1Esy9gdTiDU3pyNDpJAFoh5GyBhak+ggMCaxYpcaxjPQWrZHK5WpZAopVLz1EZSyLgp7lymM0ZGzJlertd+iG7NGHWfp7bg4slGpn7WXLM6IZZe4ASih2ZzOnV2kDuru93BD8fRKfUO0w1C4DIZAgBGTSVMTAIfGgYE-CQRzAVAjAQCB-DQR5FCccRl1lNR5TUfBTnsOBf0oasQHqAAGPp1UFLV2DSHIUGoCBUCgdgF3sRwJF3YAbF6AADABNCByEuQ5LjgMAWBNNhBEUbITGAQC4AAEnQYBeRECRAIYKipFOGhxOAaQWIXVDRHsRjmLgdjOO4tBKCkmS6C0iU4B0+w1HpHFbPgTDsPqABGAj1zaKliNI8jKJ8dh9OsViOK4oxTL4gSRCEz9qFE8SBHM2T5PERS+J8FTRDUhRNO0tDiC1JiQsMsKTN46TgEs-LdJgezHIKjChFcgAmTyiJZfoSJQMiKKooKOGU04BvYARyCkcwQhSdghmC0LjIi3j+JiGKbLihKJMquSxDSgQlMy1TqHUvLrKcubSoWnizMq6rToK+qNCcpqsKaHCAGZ2q7LUur8vrApIdghtEEaxomqaZpqvSioMozwquqKVpQWKRIwxLku2hS9oyqAspyjSpCsqYzuhkrYfK66LMJmz7ocjQPnwCVpD6fotVwAgYCfCgaHaPQIEYZ7XNwkgycWim6LgyzukvVm8ASDmsC56gebqPmBde9zhbK0W4F+gKoBYqXdzZuXOaoJXef5lz1ZazXLsi5bBLWlGxM29APC8Hx9pxw7joJw2ZfZ03uYttX3ttuH7eipGnfi1GJI+oG8c0-2hnUIA)

Comment: Ok so I've actually FIXED the broken test but now I'm still stuck with the need to express the function's return as `as const` where I'd like that to be the default behavior. I'll update this post to make the fix I've made clear.

Comment: So, uh, what is the question exactly?  Is it "why is this happening"?  If so, then [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK9qpN) would be a [mre] without all the extra stuff, and you might want to change it to that so that the question focuses on the issue.  If not, then could you [edit] so that it's obvious what the question is?

Comment: @jcalz I've updated the question with what's working now and what is not; not sure if your comment came in before or after I did that.

Comment: in a nutshell I want to preserve narrow types in the functions passed in as params and not require the caller to state `as const` to force this.

Comment: My solution seems to do a job too well of inferring the arrays: https://tsplay.dev/weBXaN - they're inferred as tuples instead.

Comment: I really wish this question were more focused and succinct.  I *think* you're looking for [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjXZ8m), maybe, but I'm worried that I'm missing something because there's extra stuff.  If that *does* meet your needs, could you [edit] the question to focus on just your final problem and not any intermediate issue you found and solved? (Is `ReturnType` even relevant anymore?)  Let me know.

Comment: yes your solution is perfect, I was struggling to find a way to provide the _effect_ of `Narrowable` while also providing guardrails for the function signature. Your solution is clean and elegant and I wish I'd thought of it. :)

Do you want to express this as an "answer?